# How do I create a role and add it to guild in Hikari?

Tags: python, discord

So basically I'm trying to create a role and add it to a guild in Hikari. I've been googling and looking at the documentation but I can't seem to find anything to add a role and if this is not possible are there any workarounds?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you were looking for is located [here](https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari/impl/rest.html#hikari.impl.rest.RESTClientImpl.create_role).

`hikari.GatewayBot` has a rest client used for making api calls to Discord - this is the `rest` attribute of the bot.

In this code block, the bot will use the rest client to create a role called `new-role-name` every time is it invited to a new guild while it is online.

```py
import os
import hikari


bot = hikari.GatewayBot(os.environ["TOKEN"])

@bot.listen()
async def on_guild_join(event: hikari.GuildJoinEvent) -> None:
    await bot.rest.create_role(event.guild_id, name="new-role-name")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run()
```

Keep in mind, if the bot doesn't have the MANAGE_ROLES permission in the guild it just joined, this code will raise an [ForbiddenError](https://www.hikari-py.dev/hikari/errors.html#hikari.errors.ForbiddenError).